# Formatting url strings PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, string, url

Hi all I am sorry if this is a dumb question and I understand I might get banned for asking it but after a lot of work reading over PHP manual, reading the relevant chapters in PHP5.3 and scowering across Stackoverflow I am stuck in my tracks.

I have been universally format the  url's taken in from a Search API I have tried to use  parse_url(), trim and others unsuccessfully I decided upon str_replace

```
foreach ($jsonObj->RESULT as $value) {

 $BLekko_results[] = array(
                            'url' => strip_tags($value->url),
            'url' => str_replace("http://www.", "http://", $value->url),
                    'url' => str_replace("https://www.", "http://", $value->url),
                     'url' => str_replace( " http://", "http://", $value->url),
                     'url' => str_replace( " http://", "http://", $value->url),
                      title' => $value->url_title,); }
```

I plead humbly for you help ...

Comment: What is your question?  You aren't clear what you are trying to achieve.  Post a URL you have, and the results you are expecting.

Comment: Please rephrase your question, I don't get what your problem is.

Comment: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/amazon/

Comment: @user2562455 - what are you trying to achieve? And does it matter that there's a single quote missing from `title` on the last line?

Comment: Ok, I am trying to get uniformed url address starting with (http;//") I am doing this because part of my program compares the urls in string format to each other. I thought that the above would be able to check what type of prefix each url address had and change it to the desired (http;//") ---but it gives out h t t p s / / www. and h t t p / / www. when the desired result it h t t p / /

Comment: No the last line is taking the key (url_title) and then storing it in temp variable $value while being saved into this array under the key title. --- this part is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($jsonObj->RESULT as $value) {
    $url = trim($value->url);
    $find = array("http://www.", "https://www.", "https://");
    $BLekko_results[] = array(
        'url' => str_replace($find, "http://", $url),
        'title' => $value->url_title,);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it really is appreciated a lot sending you good Karma :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try something like this:

```
public function processURLString($urlString) {
    $urlString = trim($urlString);

    if($urlString) {
        $urlString = preg_replace('/https?:\/\//', '', $urlString);
        $urlString = trim($urlString);
        $urlString  = 'http://'.$urlString;
    }

    return $urlString;
}
```

And then you can add or remove www etc...

Comment: Thank you very much Brannon I appreciate you taking your time to help out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$BLekko_results = array();
foreach ($jsonObj->RESULT as $value) {
    $value = strip_tags($value->url);
    $updatedURL = str_replace(array('http://www.','https://www.','https://'),"http://",$value->url);
    $updatedTitle = $value->url_title;
    $BLekko_results[] = array('url'=>$updatedURL,'title'=>$updatedTitle);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($BLekko_results);
echo "</pre>";
```